# Magento calculate shipping to be refunded on partial refund

Tags: php, magento-1.6

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate the shipping refund on orders where some of the items are being refunded.  Currently, in the credit memo screen, the amount in the input field is the total amount paid for shipping.  When you adjust the quantity of items being refunded, and hit update, the shipping refunded amounts stays the same.  I'd like to adjust it to be the portion of shipping that is related to the items being refunded.

As a calculation, I was thinking this would be:
total shipping cost - new calculation of shipping for items not being refunded = shipping cost of items being refunded.

I can see that the calculation for shipping is done in this class:
Mage_Sales_Model_Order_Creditmemo_Total_Shipping

However, I am having trouble figuring out how I would rerun the shipping calculation for the credit memo items.

Anyone have any thoughts on how I might be able to accomplish this?